# In Powershell, what's the quickest way to tell if two files are different?

Tags: scripting, powershell

Given two files (in this case, largish CSV files), what's the most efficient way in Powershell to determine if their content differs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a dos command which will do it

```
comp.exe 1.txt 2.txt
```